# Error: mitmproxy requires Python 3.5 or above

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I have installed mitmproxy with pip install
Some conflicting requirements poped up

```
 thrift-sasl 0.3.0 has requirement thrift>=0.10.0, but you'll have thrift 0.9.3 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-tensorboard 0.1.5 has requirement bleach==1.5.0, but you'll have bleach 2.1.2 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-tensorboard 0.1.5 has requirement html5lib==0.9999999, but you'll have html5lib 1.0.1 which is incompatible.
superset 0.22.1 has requirement cryptography==1.9, but you'll have cryptography 2.1.4 which is incompatible.
superset 0.22.1 has requirement markdown==2.6.8, but you'll have markdown 2.6.11 which is incompatible.
superset 0.22.1 has requirement pandas==0.20.3, but you'll have pandas 0.22.0 which is incompatible.
superset 0.22.1 has requirement python-dateutil==2.6.0, but you'll have python-dateutil 2.6.1 which is incompatible.
superset 0.22.1 has requirement six==1.10.0, but you'll have six 1.11.0 which is incompatible.
flower 0.9.1 has requirement tornado==4.2.0, but you'll have tornado 4.5.3 which is incompatible.
apache-airflow 1.9.0 has requirement flask<0.12,>=0.11, but you'll have flask 0.12.2 which is incompatible.
apache-airflow 1.9.0 has requirement flask-wtf==0.14, but you'll have flask-wtf 0.14.2 which is incompatible.
apache-airflow 1.9.0 has requirement jinja2<2.9.0,>=2.7.3, but you'll have jinja2 2.10 which is incompatible.
apache-airflow 1.9.0 has requirement psutil<5.0.0,>=4.2.0, but you'll have psutil 5.4.3 which is incompatible.
airflow 1.8.0 has requirement flask<0.12,>=0.11, but you'll have flask 0.12.2 which is incompatible.
```

When I try

```
 mitmproxy --host

Error: mitmproxy requires Python 3.5 or above

Starting with version 1.0 released in 12/2016, mitmproxy no longer supports Python 2.
```

That is strange to me because I have 3.6

```
 python --version
Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install it in a new clean [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) with clear dependencies:

```
$ mkvirtualenv mitmproxy
$ pip install mitmproxy
```

Btw. your call seems to be outdated:

```
$ mitmproxy --host
usage: mitmproxy [options]
mitmproxy: error: unrecognized arguments: --host
```

Try:

```
$ mitmproxy --help
```